# Why I can't insert the pair value like this? v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({1,"A"}));?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, key-value

I have written this code, and want to insert a value in the `vector<vector>` like this:

```
v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({1,"A"}));
```

But it shows an error. I want to know why this is not possible.

Inserting an empty value works:

```
v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({}));
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void printVec(vector<pair<int,string> > &v){
    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<pair<int,string> > > v;

    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({}));
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            int x;
            string s;
            cin >> x >>s;
            v[i].push_back({x,s});
        }
    }

    v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({})); // UNABLE TO STORE A PAIR AT THE END. ONLY CAN ADD EMPTY PAIR. DON'T KNOW WHY??
    // v.push_back({}); // USING ANY OF THEM

    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        printVec(v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Why I can't insert the pair value like this?" - Because that's not valid C++. You need to *learn* the language, not just guess.

Comment: Please provide me a good source of learning C++

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) My advice is to pick either of the "Introductory, no previous programming experience" books and read them from cover to cover following along with the chapter exercises at the end of each chapter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are pushing a pair instead of a vector of pairs.

```
v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({1,"A"}));
```

This works because it considers ({}) as an empty vector of pairs.    `

```
v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({}));`
```

Although the following will work:

```
vector<pair<int,string> > temp;
temp.push_back({1, "Hi"});
v.push_back(vector<pair<int,string> >({temp}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list-initialize your vector with the `{1,"A"}` as the initializer for one element of the `std::initializer_list` constructor you need to use braces, not parentheses:

```
vector<pair<int,string>>{{1,"A"}}
```

Or alternatively, if you aren't sure how to initialize directly with an element in the vector or the above is not something you learned about yet, simply define a variable to temporarily hold the inner vector you want to push into `v`, push the pair element into it and then use that variable. Then you don't have to guess anything:

```
vector<pair<int,string>> inner;
inner.push_back({1,"A"});
 
v.push_back(inner); // alternatively `std::move(inner)` if `inner` is not used later
```

---

`vector<pair<int,string> >({})` works because the `{}` argument can initialize the `std::initializer_list` of the `std::initializer_list`-constructor for `std::vector` directly to be empty. An additional set of braces in your original attempt would have worked the same way as well, although then the parentheses would be redundant.